# How can I set NaN (Not a Number) to zero in SpinEdit Devexpress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

```
@Html.DevExpress().SpinEditFor(m => m.MLComPrice,
                    settings => {
                                    settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "F";
                                    settings.Properties.ValueChangedDelay = 1;
                                    settings.Properties.MaxLength = 6;
                                    settings.Properties.MinValue = 0;
                                    settings.Properties.MaxValue = 100;
                    }).GetHtml()
```

If I digit only " , " in SpinEdit, it show NaN, how can I set this to Zero ?